# Неужели это глаголы?

Tags: лингвистика

Мой вопрос относится к словам "был", "буду", "были", "будут", "будешь", "была". С точки зрения обывательской логики, они ведь не описывают никаких действий. Но мы обязаны считать их глаголами! Похоже, это некий парадокс. То есть, раз уж это принятая условность, то не предоставить ли людям самим решать, как написать (вместе или слитно) - "небыл" или "не был".

Comment: "никаких" лучше писать слитно, а "не был" - соединять не надо.

Comment: @Фиофан Долотонин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5):

Глаголы, уважаемый Фиофан (Феофан?), обозначают не только действие, но и, как известно из программы начальной школы, состояние. Глагол "быть" вполне соответствует значению "состояние".

Answer (score 0):

Так глаголы обозначают не только действие.

Answer (score 0):

Кроме всего перечисленного, глаголы в неопределённой форме могут иметь только окончания ТЬ (думать, писать), ТИ (нести, ползти) и нулевое (беречь, стеречь). По форме БЫТЬ как раз имеет окончание ТЬ.